# Return Specific User in Django

Tags: python, sql, django

Still pretty new with Django and trying to work out how to display current user's profile when clicking 'view profile' through the nav-bar and the specific user when clicking 'view profile' on someone else's project page. Currently, when clicking on the nav-bar, it correctly returns the current user's profile, however, when clicking to see someone else's page on the project detail page, it still returns current user and not the desired user's profile page.

I still want the url to show up like so:
'accounts/*username*/view_profile' and not 'accounts/*pk*/view_profile'

I've tried to the 'get_context_data' method in my ViewProfileView but it returns an error about calling the url with slugs or object pk.

**models.py** I think I have the slug properly set up but I'm not sure how to implement it or if that will even solve my problem here - I've tried adding the slug to the url-conf and passing it through the get_context_data in **views.py** but I could never get it to work properly, just error after error.

```
...
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, db_index=True, unique=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True) 
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile")
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    linkedin_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    github_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.user.username
        super(Profile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

**views.py** Here you can see my attempt at the get_context_data. get_object returns the current user which works when navigating through the nav-bar but not when navigating through another person's project post. Is there a way to make it dynamic to where I can return get_object if the request is through the nav-bar and something else when the request is through the profile page?

```
...
class ViewProfileView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'registration/view_profile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user.profile

    # def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    #     users = Profile.objects.all()
    #     ctx = super(ViewProfileView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)

    #     page_user = get_object_or_404(Profile, id=self.kwargs['username'])

    #     ctx['page_user'] = page_user
    #     return ctx
...
```

**urls.py**

```
...
app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', SignUpView.as_view(), name='signup'),
    path('<str:username>/edit_user/', EditUserView.as_view(), name='edit_user'),
    path('password/', ChangePasswordView.as_view(), name='change-password'),
    path('password_success/', password_success, name='password_success'),
    path('<str:username>/view_profile/', ViewProfileView.as_view(), name='view_profile'),
    path('<str:username>/edit_profile/', EditProfileView.as_view(), name='edit_profile')
]
```

**base.html** *(nav-bar, going to self - works)*

```
...
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile' user.username %}">View Profile</a>
...
```

**project_detail.html** *(going to another user's profile but returns self, does not work)*

```
...
<a href="{% url 'accounts:view_profile' project.owner.username %}">View Profile</a><br></small></i>
...
```

Thank you for your time! Any help is greatly, greatly appreciated! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `Profile` object that links to the user with the given username, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ViewProfileView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'registration/view_profile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

In the template you work with the `object`, for example you can render:

```
{{ object.user.username }}: {{ object.about }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I just tested that out and it's giving me the same result as before - returns the currently logged in users profile when viewing through the **project_detail.html**

Comment: @ZaneWilson: exactly what is the url? In the `base.html` you are using the username of the logged in user. You thus need a link with a different username to test this. You thus should make sure that the username in the URL is from a different user to test this.

Comment: current logged in user: Zane. Viewing 'newuser' project. URL shows 'accounts/*newuser*/view_profile - which is right - but then returns Zane's profile info, the current logged in user instead of *newuser*'s profile page

Comment: @ZaneWilson: how do you render the `Profile` data, with `{{ object.about }}`? Notice that you can not use `{{ user.username }}` for example, since the `user` passed in the context is (always) the logged in user. You thus use `object` in the template to render data for that user with `newuser` as username.

Comment: You sir are a genius, that was exactly it. Can't believe I didn't catch that myself. Thank you so so so much!!!!